# amchart : how to dynamic create chart from mysql result?

Tags: javascript, php, amcharts

I am use php+mysql+amchart and use dataLoader an json url to create flow chart  and reload every 300 second like MRTG ...

It is work if manually fixed in advance....[flow chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YvqCL.png)

But the source and the number of charts I would like dynamic from MySQL.
e.g. The dashboard is displayed only in the database "Display status" = Y record.

Working code is below,
sample json file: [enter link description here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B64SEyiCYcyPNE1jZTh2emVXLXM/view?usp=sharing)

```
var Dashboard = function () {
    return {
        initFlow1: function () {
            var chart = AmCharts.makeChart("Flow1", {
                "type": "serial",
                "dataLoader": {
                    "url": "http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/admin/flowjson/25",
                    "reload": 300
                },
                "categoryField": "date",
                "dataDateFormat": "YYYY-MM-DD HH:NN:SS",
                "theme": "light",
                "categoryAxis": {
                    "minPeriod": "ss",
                    "parseDates": true
                },
                "chartCursor": {
                    "enabled": true,
                    "categoryBalloonDateFormat": "JJ:NN:SS"
                },
                "chartScrollbar": {
                    "enabled": true
                },
                "trendLines": [],
                "graphs": [{
                        "fillAlphas": 0.7,
                        "id": "AmGraph-1",
                        "lineAlpha": 0,
                        "title": "Inbound",
                        "valueField": "inFlows",
                    },
                    {
                        "fillAlphas": 0.7,
                        "id": "AmGraph-2",
                        "lineAlpha": 0,
                        "title": "Outbound",
                        "valueField": "outFlows"
                    }
                ],
                "guides": [],
                "valueAxes": [{
                    "id": "ValueAxis-1",
                    "title": "bits per second (M)"
                }],
                "allLabels": [],
                "balloon": {},
                "legend": {
                    "enabled": true
                },
                "titles": [{
                    "id": "Title-1",
                    "size": 15,
                    "text": "Flow - 1"
                }]
            })
            //1000=1秒
            setInterval(function () {
                chart.validateData()
            }, 299000);
        },

        initFlow2: function () {
            var chart = AmCharts.makeChart("Flow2", {
                "type": "serial",
                "dataLoader": {
                    "url": "http:///xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/admin/flowjson/26",
                    "reload": 300
                },
                "categoryField": "date",
                "dataDateFormat": "YYYY-MM-DD HH:NN:SS",
                "theme": "light",
                "categoryAxis": {
                    "minPeriod": "ss",
                    "parseDates": true
                },
                "chartCursor": {
                    "enabled": true,
                    "categoryBalloonDateFormat": "JJ:NN:SS"
                },
                "chartScrollbar": {
                    "enabled": true
                },
                "trendLines": [],
                "graphs": [{
                        "fillAlphas": 0.7,
                        "id": "AmGraph-1",
                        "lineAlpha": 0,
                        "title": "Inbound",
                        "valueField": "inFlows"
                    },
                    {
                        "fillAlphas": 0.7,
                        "id": "AmGraph-2",
                        "lineAlpha": 0,
                        "title": "Outbound",
                        "valueField": "outFlows"
                    }
                ],
                "guides": [],
                "valueAxes": [{
                    "id": "ValueAxis-1",
                    "title": "bits per second (M)"
                }],
                "allLabels": [],
                "balloon": {},
                "legend": {
                    "enabled": true
                },
                "titles": [{
                    "id": "Title-1",
                    "size": 15,
                    "text": "Flow -2 "
                }]
            })
            //1000=1秒
            setInterval(function () {
                chart.validateData()
            }, 299000);
        },

        init: function () {
            this.initFlow1();
            this.initFlow2();

        }
    };

}();

if (App.isAngularJsApp() === false) {
    jQuery(document).ready(function () {
        Dashboard.init(); // init metronic core componets
    });
}
```

```html
<div id="Flow1" class="CSSAnimationChart"></div>
<div id="Flow2" class="CSSAnimationChart"></div>
<script src="https://www.amcharts.com/lib/3/amcharts.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.amcharts.com/lib/3/serial.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.amcharts.com/lib/3/themes/light.js"></script>
<script src="../../assets/pages/scripts/dashboardTest.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="http://www.amcharts.com/lib/3/plugins/dataloader/dataloader.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Comment: Your code looks fine (except for the setInterval code that calls validateData - that's not necessary with reload). Post a sample of your data.

Comment: @xorspark 
thanks!!
json sample data : https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B64SEyiCYcyPNE1jZTh2emVXLXM/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Data looks fine too ([codepen](https://codepen.io/team/amcharts/pen/f7661251700fabe80e23b2f30306716f?editors=0010)). I guess I'm misunderstanding your question. Are you just asking how to best set up your code so that your JS knows to create/setup charts that autoreload on its own without manually creating a dozen or so initFlow* methods? Let me know and I can provide a minimal (static) example for you to work with.